# Convert multiple rows into one row with multiple columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I understand that there is this command called `PIVOT` and that's what I probably need but first time trying to use it, seems like I can't get its syntax to work.

So here is my sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
    CompanyName NVARCHAR(20),
    Price INT,
    Project NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (CompanyName, Price, Project)
VALUES ('Dell', 450, 'Cleaning'),
       ('Dell', 150, 'Vaccuming'),
       ('Dell', 1200, 'Painting'),
       ('Dell', 100, 'VendingMachines'),
       ('Dell', 600, 'Wallpapers'),
       ('Dell', 820, 'Carpeting')
```

I want those `Project Name` turn into columns so for example having columns like "Cleaning" , "Carpeting" , etc and then value of each column is the `Price`.

This is what I tried so far but it is wrong syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT CompanyName, Price, Project
     FROM dbo.MyTable) src
PIVOT
    (SUM(Price)
        FOR Project IN ('Cleaning', 'Vaccuming', 'Painting', 'VendingMachines', 'Wallpapers', 'Carpeting')
    ) piv;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracket `[]` your column names

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3f16647fe64e3ec7edb60ff4e4c3d886)**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT  CompanyName, Price, Project
  FROM dbo.MyTable
) src
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Price)
  FOR Project IN ([Cleaning], [Vaccuming], [Painting], [VendingMachines], [Wallpapers], [Carpeting])
) piv;
```